# React development server is not functioning properly for 10% of users

Tags: reactjs

I hope it's the right place to ask such question. I have a live react app which still runs in development mode since it requires frequent updates, and it seems that for a few users the website doesn't function properly while for the others it works perfectly.

For example, for a few users there is a button that just doesn't respond, although I created some code to log to the console that the button was pressed, and it does also for those users, but then the rest of the code just doesn't run.

For other users, there is some text that loaded from mongodb database, and for those users it reverses some of the words in a random fashion.

I'm really lost here and don't even know where to begin, since for me and most of the users everything is working fine.

Do you think it could be because the app still runs in development mode?

Recently I noticed that a few users received the message

```
the development server has disconnected. refresh the page if necessary.
```

I researched this and was suggested that I should upgrade my react-scripts. I did, and the problem vanished, but the other problems still persist.

I understand that it's like shooting in the dark and it's hard to give advices without knowing more information, but maybe you could point me in the right direction?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: `I'm really lost here and don't even know where to begin` - not deploying in development mode ?

Comment: As far as you know, deploying development mode can cause such weird problems?

Comment: @sir-haver well, it shouldn't but we can't see how everything on your end is configured. deploying in production mode would be a good place to start debugging.